# add header to the first column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to add header to the first column called "TYPE"-
this is the result I get:
[image]

this is the result I want:
[image]

thanks

Comment: Please produce a sample of your data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, my answer will be useful or not. But I faced same problem and I solved this problem in following way.

```
library(tidyverse)

rownames_to_column(mtcars,var = "Type") -> df
df
```

Thanks!!...

Answer (score 1):

I understand correctly you  want to name... the row names there is no way to do this unless you get the row names and make a column of it
You seem to think  row names is a column

Answer (score 0):

```
col.names(yourtable)[1] <- "Type"
```

Comment: It will work if first column contains this names. But if this first column is attribute `rownames` then I'm afraid there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: not working... this just rename the second column... and if i try to do col.names(cars)[0] its give me error: Error in col.names(cars)[0] <- "Type" : 
  could not find function "col.names"

Comment: Actually I think that the functioni is:
colnames(df)[1] <- "Type"